# git is recreating folders with different index

Tags: git, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, atlassian-sourcetree

I don't know if this is issue connected to SourceTree git or PhpStorm git, because I have both connected to the same project. But sometimes whenever I come back to my pc it recreates folders like this:

[image: this]

If anyone had the same issue please help me. Because it becomes so annoying to delete it all the time. It is on iOs if thats gonna help somehow.

Comment: Do they have a setting such as `auto pull` or similar that aims to keep the repo in sync with remote? If there is, it might be a start to disable them.

Comment: You've put your directory on some sharing service (e.g., iCloud) and it's this *sharing service* that is creating these. Don't put Git repositories on shared media.

Comment: @torek , thank you so much. This was the issue...